# Exercise tracker that's not gym-oriented

Tags: android, fitness

I found an exercise program which promises to improve body posture, and want to do it. I want to do the exercises I do from it on a daily basis, using my Android phone. And I was thinking that, if I start using such a tool, I'd also like to record other types of exercise I do.

I tried a few popular workout and fitness loggers, and I was thoroughly disappointed. They all seem to be oriented towards people who go to the gym to do strength exercises. I need something that's flexible enough to allow for the tracking of another type of exercise.

**Features I need**

- Be able to add custom exercises
- Be able to use custom exercise categories - preferably, by using a non-hierarchical ad-hoc taxonomy similar to SO tags
- Be able to use custom units for "reps". For example, the first exercise of the program is done for "8 breaths per side". If I can't add a custom unit, then at least I should be able to write it down in the exercise description, and then be able to track my exercises without entering reps.
- Be able to create a workout plan for the day
- Have a calendar view to see on which days I exercised
- Have a statistics where I can see how many times I have done each exercise
- Use metric units

**Deal-breaker features**

- Collection of my personal data (It's OK if they save my exercises log in the cloud, but they shouldn't track my weight or similar info)
- A forced taxonomy (such as having to categorize each exercise as "cardio" vs. "strength" or assign it to a muscle group)
- subscription payment model. If it's paid, I'd be OK with spending up to 10 Euro for a one-time payment.

**Non-essential features**
If the app has one of the "prefer not to have" features in this section, then the feature should be easy to ignore, such as being hidden in a tab I don't need to visit.

- I would like to be able to annotate the exercise with the equipment needed, and then being able to see the list of equipment for a planned workout. Having this feature is non-essential, but if it does exist, it's non-negotiable that I should be able to edit the list of equipment I can choose from.
- no notifications (such as duolingo-style "time to exercise again")
- No database of exercise descriptions.
- I prefer it to *not* have a feature that suggests workouts for me.
- also unnecessary: calorie counter, plate calculator, being congratulated on increasing reps, motivation schemes such as counting streaks or gamification elements.
- I would like to be able to also record sport activities which aren't measured like a workout, such as noting that I have played some badminton that day.

Comment: While waiting for matching recommendatios: maybe my list of [Fitness](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/sport_fitness) apps has something for you (I'm not using any such app, so I cannot name one meeting your requirements). As by your privacy requirements, I'd first check those with an F-Droid icon (and take it from F-Droid), then those with a star ("no known trackers"), then those with the least monitor (tracker) icons and lowest numbers in the gray circles (tracker count).